# Articles about Mather's Geometric Groups?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, group-actions

I'm trying to find some information about "Mather's Geometric Groups". But the information on that subject is quite scarce, the only thing I found was the "Mather's Geometric Lemma" in the book "Local Features in Natural Images via Singularity Theory" by J. Damon.

I really appreciate your help, thanks.